# How to insert two constants using srec_cat?

Tags: srec-cat

I have the following script for [srec_cat](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/).  My goal is to insert two constants into known locations in a .srec file:

```
srcfile.srec
# carve a hole for and insert crc byte count
-exclude 0x43c8 0x43cc
-generate 0x43c8 0x43cc -constant-l-e 0x8e2c 4
# carve a hole for and insert crc expected value
-exclude 0x43cc 0x43d0
-generate 0x43cc 0x43d0 -constant-l-e 0x194fa71a 4
# output into new file
-o dstfile.srec
```

If I comment out either half, the script works without error.  But with both present, I get the message:

```
srec_cat: generate repeat data: multiple 0x000043CC values (previous = 0x00, this one = 0x1A)
```

I could write out an intermediate file and process it to insert the second constant, but that seems rather heavy handed.  Save me from such a hack!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need brackets as mentioned in [man `srec_examples`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/srec_examples.1.html):

> **Filtering After Joining**
>          There are times when you want to join two sets of data together, and then apply a filter to the joined result.  To do this
>   you use parentheses.
>
> ```
> srec_cat                                                  \
>     '('                                                   \
>         infile -exclude 0xFFF0 0x10000                      \
>         -generate 0xFFF0 0xFFF8 -repeat‐string 'Bananas ' \
>     ')'                                                   \
>     -b‐e‐length 0xFFF8 4                                  \
>     -b‐e‐checksum‐neg 0xFFFC 4 4                          \
>     -o outfile
> ```
>
> The above example command catenates an input file (with the generated data area excluded) with a constant string.  This catenated
>   input is then filtered to add a 4‐byte length, and a 4‐byte checksum.

In your case:

```
srec_cat '(' srcfile.srec -exclude 0x43c8 0x43cc -generate 0x43c8 0x43cc -l-e-constant 0x8e2c 4 ')' -exclude 0x43cc 0x43d0 -generate 0x43cc 0x43d0 -l-e-constant 0x194fa71a 4 -o dstfile.srec
```